# How to configure Laravel 5.1 to log to syslog?

Tags: laravel

I am using 5.1 version of Laravel with PHP 5.6. From Laravel website, I gather that it will be possible to log to syslog via their monolog library. But I can't find any examples on how to do that. Can you please tell me how to log to syslog from Laravel? I tried setting the `APP_LOG=syslog` in .env file. That causes Laravel to stop logging to file but it does not log anything to syslog. How do I specify syslog server ip:port or socket address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration), you should use this in `config/app.php`:

```
'log' => 'syslog'
```

> **Log Modes**
>
> Out of the box, Laravel supports single, daily, syslog and errorlog
>   logging modes. For example, if you wish to use daily log files instead
>   of a single file, you should simply set the log value in your
>   `config/app.php` configuration file.

Comment: I did that but it does not seem to work. I have other non-php applications that can write to the same syslog.

Comment: You can set `LOG_CHANNEL=syslog` in your *.env* file too and it will work with a default 5.7 app

Answer (score 0):

It says in the docs to set the `log` value in your config file `config/app.php` to syslog:

```
'log' => 'syslog'
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#configuration